# ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED does not update EXTRA_STATUS of device

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast, batterymanager

I am using `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent-filter to receive broadcast messages from android.

I am using following code

```
 IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
 Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
 BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(status));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(status), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
        float battPct = (level/(float)scale) * 100;
        txtBatteryPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(battPct));
        txtBatteryStatus.setText(String.valueOf(isCharging));
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }else {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
};
```

Here i m checking the battery charging status as described in android official documentation.

When i ran the application in charging mode, it gives me `EXTRA_STATUS` values as 2 i.e `BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING` which is expected. But when disconnect the charger from device and get another broadcast from android, It still send me same status as if charging. It was expected to be send me the status `BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING`.

Why it does not update the status while sending updated broadcast ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/getting-battery-details/).